# How to add offset to the popup menu?

Tags: react-native-popup-menu

I want to offset the menu that pops over my button. I would like the popup to not obstruct the button clicked.

I read the doc and attempted to add styling but couldn't find where and how to add the style. The doc mentions that some component of this library accept a `customStyles` prop, but it errors whenever I try to give it something, like `<MenuOptions customStyles={{top: 10}}>`.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

```
<MenuOptions customStyles={{optionsContainer: {marginTop: 30}}}>
```